# Help with Poisson Random Variables.

Tags: probability, statistics

The problem is if $\lambda=1/2$.

Find $E[X]$, $E[2-X]$, $E[X^2]$ and $Var[2X]$.

I know that $E[X]$ is simply $1/2$.

But as for finding the other ones, I am lost. I'm assuming I'll have to create and compute some sort of infinite sum, but am unsure where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may know that the variance of the Poisson distribution is $\lambda$. Then:

$$
EX = \lambda\\
E(2-X) = 2-\lambda\\
E(X^2) = Var(X) + (EX)^2 = \lambda+\lambda^2\\
Var(2X) = 4Var(X) = 4\lambda
$$